# Comprimir un archivo en zip en c#

Tags: c#, zip

Holas, estoy comprimiendo un archivo XML a zip, logro realizar bien el proceso de comprensión sin embargo mi problema está que dentro de mi archivo ZIP el archivo XML pierde su extensión.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public string CrearZIP(string FileToAdd)
    {
        string[] Names = FileToAdd.Split('.');
        string FileZipName = Names[0].ToString() + ".zip";

        using (FileStream fOrigen = File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(path + @"\Data\", FileToAdd)))
        {
            using (FileStream fDestino = File.Create(Path.Combine(path + @"\Envio\", FileZipName)))
            {

                byte[] buffer = new byte[fOrigen.Length];
                fOrigen.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                using (GZipStream output = new GZipStream(fDestino, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
            }
        }

        return FileZipName;
    }
```

Y mi archivo ZIP, dentro de muestra así, sin la extensión XML que viene del archivo inicial:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda.

Comment: que biblioteca estas usando para crear el zip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clase que estás usando `GZipStream` es solo para comprimir streams y no es un compresor que tenga noción de qué cosa es un archivo en formato zip.

Si lo que quieres es crear un archivo .zip u otro de los disímiles formatos de compresión que hoy existen, debes decidir al menos entre 2 opciones:

- Usar una librería externa (ej. nuget) que te facilite el trabajo (y la reutilización)
- Usar algo incluido en el framework, como por ejemplo `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive` sabiendo que solo podrás soportar ficheros zip, que por cierto es el formato con el que menor radio de compresión obtienes generalmente.

### Usar una librería.

Puedes buscar y encontraras varias. En mi experiencia de las que son libres, no son perfectas ni tan sencillas y las mejores son pagadas. Pero algunas de las que puedes usar son:

- [DotNetZip](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=dotnetzip)
- [SevenZipSharp](https://github.com/squid-box/SevenZipSharp)

### Usar clases incluidas en el framework.

Si solo quieres soportar el formato zip, puedes usar [`System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=netframework-4.7.2). Algo como esto:

#### Para crear un archivo:

```
Agrega referencias a `System.IO.Compression` y `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`.

using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

public void CrearZip(string fileToAdd)
{
    var outFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileToAdd) + ".zip";
    var fileNameToAdd = Path.Combine(path, "data", fileToAdd);
    var zipFileName = Path.Combine(path, "envio", outFileName);

    //Crear el archivo (si quieres puedes editar uno existente cambiando el modo a Update.
    using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(zipFileName, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(fileNameToAdd, Path.GetFileName(fileNameToAdd));
    }
}
```

#### Para extraer hacia un directorio:

```
using (var archive = ZipFile.Open(zipFileName, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
{
    archive.ExtractToDirectory(@"c:\directorio\donde\extraer\archivo");
}
```

Hay muchas más operaciones que puedes hacer con el Api de ZipArchive que puedes ver en la documentación que te dejé más arriba. Una de las más convenientes es:

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
```

Que como su nombre lo indica, te permite crear un zip a partir de los ficheros en un directorio.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Excelente estimado, muchas gracias por el apoyo.