# El nombre del directorio no es valido

Tags: c#, .net, zip

Hola comunidad tengo la siguiente duda que espero ustedes con mas experiencia me puedan apoyar en resolver, estoy realizando un programa que comprima los archivos en formato ZIP, para eso estoy usando la librería **"System.IO.Compression.FileSystem",** el problema surge cuando intento guardar el archivo ya  comprimido ya que Visual Studio me arroja una excepción con temas del directorio.

Espero me puedan apoyar para resolver esta duda.

Gracias.

```
namespace ZIP
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    OpenFileDialog Open = new OpenFileDialog();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Open.ShowDialog();
        textBox1.Text = Open.FileName;
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Title = "guardar archivo comprimido";
        sfd.Filter = "Archivos comprimidos ZIP|*.zip";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog().Equals(DialogResult.OK))
        {
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(textBox1.Text,sfd.FileName);
            MessageBox.Show("Archivos comprimidos", "Aviso");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si lo que quieres es comprimir un archivo consulta [stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/244847/comprimir-un-archivo-en-zip-en-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es esta línea:

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(textBox1.Text,sfd.FileName);
```

Está intentando comprimir una carpeta sin embargo tú le estás proporcionando la ruta de tu archivo y no la carpeta en sí. Por tal motivo si deseas comprimir solamente el archivo y seguir usando la misma librería es hacer los siguientes pasos en código:

1. Crear una carpeta temporal
2. Mover el archivo a la carpeta temporal
3. Comprimir la ruta de la carpeta temporal
4. Eliminar la carpeta temporal

De esta forma podrías comprimir solo el archivo